# JavaScript Math.random() returning Nan

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript and have been tasked with creating a simplified version of BlackJack. I've created 4 variables: var card1 = 0; same for card2, card3, and card4. To my understanding that would create a numeric variable. Then when I try to get a random number assigned to them, it's returning NaN.

```js
var card1 = 0;
var card2 = 0;
var card3 = 0;
var card4 = 0;

card1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11 + 2);
card2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11 + 2);
card3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11 + 2);
card4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11 + 2);

console.log(card1, card2, card3, card4);
```

I've tried adding parseInt before the random with the same result. Any suggestions?

Comment: well, i mean, no, it's not. Your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Your snippet just work here. What browser are you using?

Comment: Can you show us the code where the values are NaN? Perhaps something went wrong between assigning values to card1...card4 and using them.

Comment: I believe there is more code than what you're posting here, because that code in itself does work.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with the code you posted, at least in regards to `NaN` (Not a Number) values. Anyways, here is a nice fully-working `HTML, CSS, JS` Blackjack game. Maybe it can help you to find where you made mistakes, or at least inspire you go around this 'problem' in a slightly different manner.

```js
<script>
window.addEventListener("load", start, false);

function start()
{
 play();
}

function play()
{
 var deck1 = new Deck();
 deck1.createDeck();
 deck1.shuffle();
 deck1.deal21();
 document.getElementById("hit").addEventListener("click", function(){deck1.hit();},false);
 document.getElementById("stand").addEventListener("click", function(){deck1.stand();},false);
 document.getElementById("replay").addEventListener("click", function(){deck1.deal21();}, false);
}

function Deck()
{
 this.deck = new Array();
 this.userTotal;
 this.dealerTotal;
 this.money = 100;
 this.userBust;
 this.dealerBust;
 this.curusrHand;
 this.curdlrHand;
 var userHand = document.getElementById("user-hand");
 var dealerHand = document.getElementById("dealer-hand");
 var userScore = document.getElementById("user-score");
 var dealerScore = document.getElementById("dealer-score");
 var status = document.getElementById("game-status");
 var moneyDiv = document.getElementById("money");

 this.newDeck = function newDeck()
 {
  this.createDeck();
  this.shuffle();
  status.innerHTML="NEW DECK IN PLAY!";
 }

 this.createDeck = function createDeck()
 {
  var numCards=0;
  var suit, symbol, name;
  for(var k=1; k<=4; k++)
  {
   switch(k)
   {
    case 1: suit ="hearts";
    break;
    case 2: suit ="diamonds";
    break;
    case 3: suit ="spades";
    break;
    case 4: suit ="clubs";
    break;
   }

   for(var i=1; i<=13; i++)
   {
    symbol = i;
    switch(i)
    {
     case 1: name= "Ace";
     symbol = "A";
     break;
     case 2: name= "two";
     break;
     case 3: name= "three";
     break;
     case 4: name= "four";
     break;
     case 5: name= "five";
     break;
     case 6: name= "six";
     break;
     case 7: name= "seven";
     break;
     case 8: name= "eight";
     break;
     case 9: name= "nine";
     break;
     case 10: name= "ten";
     break;
     case 11: name= "jack";
     symbol = "J";
     break;
     case 12: name= "queen";
     symbol = "Q";
     break;
     case 13: name= "king";
     symbol = "K";
     break;
    }
    this.deck[numCards] = new Card(suit, i, name, symbol);
    numCards++;
   }
  }
 }

 this.shuffle = function shuffle()
 {
  var randomDeck = new Array();
  var empty = false;
  while(!empty)
  {
  var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*this.deck.length);
  randomDeck.push(this.deck[randomIndex]);
  this.deck.splice(randomIndex, 1);
  if(this.deck.length <=0) empty = true;
  }
  for(var i=0; i<randomDeck.length; i++)
  {
   this.deck[i] = randomDeck[i];
  }
 };


 this.calcValue = function calcValue(hand)
 {
  var val = 0;
  var tempArr = hand;
  tempArr.sort(function(a,b) { return parseFloat(a.val) - parseFloat(b.val) } );
  for(var i=tempArr.length-1; i>=0; i--)
  {
   var temp = tempArr[i];
   if(temp.val === 1 && val <=10)temp.val = 11;
   else if(temp.val >=10) temp.val = 10;
   val += temp.val;
  }
  return val;
 };

 this.emptyDeck = function emptyDeck()
 {
  if(this.deck.length < 1) return true;
  else return false;
 }

 this.deal21 = function deal21()
 {
  status.innerHTML="";
  this.money--;
  
  //reset all the stuff that needs to be reset if the game is being replayed
  money.innerHTML= "Money: " + this.money;
  dealerHand.innerHTML="<h2>Dealer Hand</h2>";
  userHand.innerHTML="<h2>User Hand</h2>";
  this.userTotal=0;
  this.dealerTotal=0;
  this.userBust=false;
  this.dealerBust=false;
  hit.setAttribute("style", "");
  stand.setAttribute("style", "");
  dealerScore.setAttribute("style", "");
  this.curusrHand = new Array();
  this.curdlrHand = new Array();


  for(i=0; i<2; i++)
  {
   if(this.emptyDeck())this.newDeck();
   this.curusrHand.push(this.deck.pop());
   userHand.innerHTML+=this.curusrHand[i].showCard();
  }
  this.userTotal = this.calcValue(this.curusrHand);
  userScore.innerHTML=this.userTotal;

  for(i=0; i<2; i++)
  {
   if(this.emptyDeck())this.newDeck();
   this.curdlrHand.push(this.deck.pop());
   dealerHand.innerHTML+=this.curdlrHand[i].showCard();
  }
  this.dealerTotal = this.calcValue(this.curdlrHand);
  dealerScore.innerHTML=this.dealerTotal;
  //hide dealers first card
  var firstCard = dealerHand.getElementsByClassName("card")[0];
  firstCard.setAttribute("id", "hidden-card");
  var blackjack =true;
  if(this.userTotal === 21 && this.dealerTotal < 21) this.gameOver(blackjack);
  else if(this.dealerTotal === 21) this.gameOver();
 };

 this.hit = function hit()
 {
  if(this.emptyDeck())this.newDeck();
  this.curusrHand.push(this.deck.pop());
  userHand.innerHTML+=this.curusrHand[this.curusrHand.length-1].showCard();
  this.userTotal = this.calcValue(this.curusrHand);
  userScore.innerHTML=this.userTotal;
  if(this.userTotal >21) 
   {
    userScore.innerHTML+=" <span style='color:red; font-weight: bold;'> BUST</span>";
    this.userBust = true;
    this.gameOver();
   }
 };

 this.stand = function stand()
 {
  while(this.dealerTotal < 17)
  {
   if(this.emptyDeck())this.newDeck();
   this.curdlrHand.push(this.deck.pop());
   dealerHand.innerHTML+=this.curdlrHand[this.curdlrHand.length-1].showCard();
   this.dealerTotal = this.calcValue(this.curdlrHand);
   dealerScore.innerHTML=this.dealerTotal;
   if(this.dealerTotal > 21) 
    {
     dealerScore.innerHTML+=" <span style='color:red; font-weight: bold;'> BUST</span>";
     this.dealerBust = true;
    }
  }
  this.gameOver();
 }

 this.gameOver = function gameOver(blackjack)
 {
  document.getElementById("hidden-card").setAttribute("id","");
  dealerScore.setAttribute("style", "visibility: visible;");
  hit.setAttribute("style", "visibility:hidden;");
  stand.setAttribute("style", "visibility:hidden;");

  if(blackjack) 
  {
   this.money +=3;
   status.innerHTML ="BLACKJACK!!!!!!!!!";
  }

  else if(this.userTotal > this.dealerTotal && this.userBust === false || this.dealerBust ===true)
  {
   //user wins
   this.money+=2;
   status.innerHTML ="YOU WIN!";
  }
  else if(this.userTotal === this.dealerTotal && this.userBust === false)
  {
   //push
   this.money++;
   status.innerHTML="PUSH :o";
  }

  else status.innerHTML="YOU LOSE!";

  money.innerHTML="Money: "+this.money;

 }

 this.dump = function dump()
 {
  for(var i=0; i<this.deck.length; i++)
  {
   this.deck[i].showCard();
  }
 };
}

function Card(suit, val, name, symbol)
{
  this.suit = suit;
  this.val = val;
  this.name = name;
  this.symbol = symbol;

 this.showCard =function showCard()
 {
  var html="";
  switch(this.suit)
  {
   case "hearts": suit_text = "&hearts;";
   break;
   case "diamonds": suit_text = "&diams;";
   break;
   case "spades": suit_text = "&spades;";
   break;
   case "clubs": suit_text = "&clubs;";
   break;
  }
  html="<div class='card " + this.suit + "'><div class='card-value'>" + this.symbol + "</div><div class='suit'>" + suit_text + "</div><div class='main-number'>"+this.symbol +"</div><div class='invert card-value'>"+this.symbol+"</div><div class='invert suit'>"+suit_text+"</div></div>";
  return html;
 }
}
</script>
```

```css
div.card
{
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100px;
 height: 150px;
 border: solid 1px #333;
 border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 10px;
 position: relative;
}

div.card.hearts, div.card.diamonds
{
 color: red;
}

div.card div.main-number
{
 font-size: 36px;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0px auto;
 margin-top: 50px;
}

div.card-value, div.suit
{
 position: absolute;
 left: 5px;
}

div.card-value{top: 5px;}
div.card-value{top: 20px;}

div.card-value.invert, div.suit.invert
{
 transform: rotate(180deg);
 right: 5px;
 text-align: right;
 top: auto;
 left: auto;
}

div.card-value.invert{bottom: 5px;}
div.suit.invert{bottom: 20px;}

div.dealer-area{}

div.user-area{float: left;}

div#user-score, div#dealer-score
{
 display: inline-block;
}

div.score-parent
{
 width: 100%;
 display: inline-block;
}

div.score-parent p
{
 display: inline-block;
}

div#dealer-score
{
 visibility: hidden;
}

div.card#hidden-card
{
 background-color: #CBE0FD;
}

div.card#hidden-card div
{
 visibility: hidden;
}

div.controls input
{
 margin-left: 20px;
 width: 200px;
}

.score-parent {
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#user-hand {
  font-family: cursive;
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#dealer-hand {
    font-family: cursive;
    color: orange;
    font-weight: bold;
}

input {
  display: inline-block;
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#money {
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  color: gold;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="game-status"></div>
 <div class="user-area">
 <div id="money"></div>
 <div id="user-buttons" class="controls">
 <input type="button" id="hit" value="Hit">
 <input type="button" id="stand" value="Stand">
 <input type="button" id="replay" value="Play Again">
 </div>
 <div class="score-parent">
      <p>Score</p>
 <div id="user-score"class="score">
   </div>
  </div>
 <div id="user-hand" class="hand">
 <h2>User Hand</h2>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="dealer-area">
 <div class="score-parent">
   <p>Current Score: </p>
  <div id="dealer-score"class="score">
     </div>
    </div>
 <div id="dealer-hand" class="hand">
 <h2>Dealer Hand</h2>
 </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html
```

Comment: Hmm, what link, buddy? If it was helpful, please accept my answer. Have a good one.